# Force VS Code to open new files as the same type as current file open

Tags: visual-studio-code

I could have sworn this was added as a feature a while back, but has now been removed with a recent update? Example, if I have my_file.ts open, and I go to new => file, I want it to create Untitled-1.ts as a TS file instead of plain text. I can't find it in the settings and I don't even know what to search for really. I'm sure it's in the settings somewhere.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. When you create a new file, vscode just opens an editor, not actually save the file. Once you save it, vscode prompt a "save file" modal..

Comment: @MoshFeu by default it's opening the file as type "Plain Text" but it should open the file as type whatever I have open at the moment. That is what it did for a while, then it was reverted. I know I even read about it in a change log I just can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. It's `files.defaultLanguage`. If you set it as `${activeEditorLanguage}` it will do what you've described. I wouldn't aware of this option before :)

[image: screenshot of settings]

[Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_how-do-i-set-the-default-language-for-new-files)

Comment: YES THERE IT IS!!! I was sure it was `${activeEditorLanguage}` before, it must have been revered by an update! I don't know why this isn't always the default as it's very very useful! Thank you!

Comment: Maybe they've changed that because of complains. I can get your point, but I can understand people who wouldn't like that.. Anyway, thanks for introducing me that feature ;)